# How to compare password with username in asp.net membership?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

How can you ensure an entered password does not match an entered username before creating a user with ASP.NET Membership?

**Update:**

I've tried setting this (in the web.config file provider section):

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression = "^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:]))(?i)(?!.*" + Username + ").+$";
```

But I'm afraid comparing it to the username like this won't work in Membership.

I also thought I could decorate the `Password` property of the `RegisterModel` class in `AccountModel` with some custom validation.

Either way I am confused and need suggestions.

Comment: If you want a direct answer you'll have to provide some code to show the mechanism by which your accounts are being created.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer, but if you set minimum password complexity requirements in the `MembershipProvider` configuration, then there should be little chance of this.

This is done in the following web.config block (for example):

```
<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="xxx" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="8" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="5" 
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$" 
             applicationName="/" 
             name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </providers>      
</membership>
```

Comment: I am ready with my regex here it is  "^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:]))(?i)(?!.*" + Username + ").+$";  But I am afraid if Comparing UserName like this works in Membership or not